# Is it justified to undo acceptance of an answer if another one, later on, gets more votes?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

Can I undo acceptance of an answer if another one ends up getting more votes than the one I initially accepted… and that other answer is mine! I mean, it adds a competitive edge to the otherwise sedate pursuit of if not truth, at least commonly received usage… !

Comment: You can do what you can do. If an answer has been edited since you accepted it you can unaccept it. Also, you can always accept your own answer. That does seem very self-serving though. And may be perceived as uncool even if objectively the most faithful thing to do. # of votes is irrelevant.

Comment: As someone who was un-greenchecked when a better answer -- an answer that I recognized as better -- was posted, it is OK to retract an acceptance.  I had no hard feelings.  To do so in favor of your own answer, however, I consider bad form.  The number of votes is irrelevant, totally irrelevant.

Comment: @ab2: how about mobbing and stalking? Is it also considered bad form?

Comment: @user58319 Why are you asking me this question?

Answer (score 6):

You are supposed to accept the answer to your question that most helped you, which may well be other than the one with the highest current vote total.

People will do what they will do, but this is the expected determinant.